# Android private styles using

Tags: android, xml, styles

Trying to inherit `Widget.TextView.ListSeparator` style, but now aapt doesn´t allow to do this:

> No resource found that matches the given name
>   'Widget.TextView.ListSeparator

because google made it private. But how can I combine two styles : ListSeparator and margins?

Style 1

```
<style name="settings_plain_text">
<item name="android:layout_marginTop"> 10sp </item>
<item name="android:layout_marginBottom"> 10sp </item>
<item name="android:textSize"> 18sp </item>
```

Style 2

```
style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
```

Answer (score 6):

I copy the answer from this [link](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18659):

> Hello all. I did some investigating with the frameworks team who's in charge of aapt.
>   What is happening is that some styles, like WindowTitle are not public (you won't find them in android.R.style). You should not be extending non public resources. aapt used to let you do that but it was a bug which was fixed in platform-tools r6.
>
> The issue is that once compiled, resources are assigned an integer. In this case your custom style is assigned an integer and its parent is referenced through the parent integer.
>
> For the framework, only public resources are guaranteed to only have the same integer, build after build. The integer of private resources integer will change from build to build.
>
> This means that your custom style is referencing a parent that *will not* be valid once installed on a device. It'll referenced either another resources or none at all, and it won't do what you want.
>
> If you wish to reuse a style that is private, you should copy the content of that style into your own instead of extending it.

The style I have found googling is [that one](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml):

```
<style name="Widget.TextView.ListSeparator">
    <item name="android:background">@android:drawable/dark_header_dither</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">?textColorSecondary</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
    <item name="android:paddingStart">8dip</item>
</style>
```

From that you can modify margins.

Comment: Oh, thanks! But dark_header_dither is also private :D
Perhaps there will be an endless chain